# stop and uninstall service in visual studio setup and deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-services, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a windows service deployment project that could start the service automatically once i installed the setup file. I have passed the argument as -i in Custom Actions - Install.

And then in in Custom Actions - Commit, I have put argument as -s.

But how to stop and uninstall service in Custom ACtions - Uninstall ?

I tried doing -k, -u as sequence, but it doesn't help

Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to [create a WIX merge module with the ServiceInstall Elemen](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)t then embed in the setup project.